# Type ambiguity in Haskell type families

Tags: haskell, type-inference, type-families

I am trying put together the following class `Domain` and its instance `TrivialDomain`

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

data Transition = Transition

class Domain d where
    type Set d
    type Engine d :: * -> *

    top :: Engine d (Set d)

    -- ...
    complement :: Set d -> Engine d (Set d)
    exclude    :: Set d -> Set d -> Engine d (Set d)
    -- ...

data TrivialDomain = TrivialDomain

instance Domain TrivialDomain where
    type Set TrivialDomain = [Int]
    type Engine TrivialDomain = IO

    top = return [0..10]

    -- ...
    complement a = top >>= (flip exclude) a
    exclude a b  = return $ filter (not . (`elem` b)) a
    -- ...
```

but I keep getting the following error which I fail to understand

```
test3.hs:25:21:
    Couldn't match type ‘Engine d0’ with ‘IO’
    The type variable ‘d0’ is ambiguous
    Expected type: IO (Set d0)
      Actual type: Engine d0 (Set d0)
    In the first argument of ‘(>>=)’, namely ‘top’
    In the expression: top >>= (flip exclude) a
test3.hs:25:35:
    Couldn't match type ‘Set d1’ with ‘[Int]’
    The type variable ‘d1’ is ambiguous
    Expected type: Set d0 -> [Int] -> IO [Int]
      Actual type: Set d1 -> Set d1 -> Engine d1 (Set d1)
    In the first argument of ‘flip’, namely ‘exclude’
    In the second argument of ‘(>>=)’, namely ‘(flip exclude) a’
```

I would expect `Engine d (Set d)` to resolve to `IO [Int]` in the instance declaration, which does not seem to be the case. At least GHC does not think so. What am I missing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your case, associated types aren't enough to infer the types of the methods.

You have class `Domain d`, and `Set` and `Engine` are associated to `d`. This means that whenever there is a known `d` in our program with a known `Domain d` instance, GHC can resolve `Set d` and `Engine d`. But this doesn't work backwards. GHC can't resolve `d` or a `Domain` instance from the presence of a `Set d` or an `Engine d`, since it's entirely possible that there are different `Domain` instances with the same `Set` and `Engine` types.

Since your class methods only mention `Set` and `Engine`, `Domain d`  can never be inferred from method use.

You could do a couple of things depending on your goals.

First, you could make `d` depend on `Set` and `Engine`:

```
class Domain set engine where
  type DomainOf set engine :: *
  -- ...
```

More generally, [`FunctionalDependencies`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/type-class-extensions.html#functional-dependencies) gives you much more flexibility to enforce dependencies between types. For example, you can specifically declare that there is only one `d` for each `Set`, which is enough to recover good type inference:

```
class Domain d set engine | d -> set engine, set -> d where

    top        :: engine set
    complement :: set -> engine set
    exclude    :: set -> set -> engine set

data TrivialDomain = TrivialDomain

instance Domain TrivialDomain [Int] IO where

    top = return [0..10]

    complement a = top >>= (flip exclude) a

    exclude a b  = return $ filter (not . (`elem` b)) a
```

Finally, if you want to use your original class, you have to add `Proxy d` parameters to your methods, in order to make the instance and the associated types resolvable:

```
import Data.Proxy

data Transition = Transition

class Domain d where
    type Set d
    type Engine d :: * -> *

    top        :: Proxy d -> Engine d (Set d)
    complement :: Proxy d -> Set d -> Engine d (Set d)
    exclude    :: Proxy d -> Set d -> Set d -> Engine d (Set d)

data TrivialDomain = TrivialDomain

instance Domain TrivialDomain where
    type Set TrivialDomain = [Int]
    type Engine TrivialDomain = IO

    top _ = return [0..10]

    complement d a = top d >>= (flip (exclude d)) a
    exclude d a b  = return $ filter (not . (`elem` b)) a
```

Here, the purpose of `Proxy d` is to specify exactly which instance you want to use.

However, this means we have to write `top (Proxy :: Proxy d)` on each method usage (similarly with other methods), which is rather onerous. With GHC 8 we can omit `Proxy`s and use [`TypeApplications`](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/TypeApplication) instead:

```
{-# language TypeApplications, TypeFamilies #-}

-- ...

instance Domain TrivialDomain where
    type Set TrivialDomain = [Int]
    type Engine TrivialDomain = IO

    top = return [0..10]

    complement a = top @TrivialDomain >>= (flip (exclude @TrivialDomain)) a
    exclude a b = return $ filter (not . (`elem` b)) a
```

Comment: regarding the last example, could you write `top @d` at the class level in GHC8?

Comment: I think we can't. By default, `forall`-bound type variables can be `@`-applied, but we can't write `forall d.` in the `Domain` method types, obviously. I've found that `@` works fine on class methods, and can be used in the order of the class type parameters.