# Why are unconditionally ambiguous methods involving type families not rejected?

Tags: haskell, types, type-families

I have the following declarations:

```
class NN a where
  type Vector a :: *

  vectorize :: Vector a -> WordVector

  compute :: a -> SomeResult
```

In an instance of `NN`, I have this:

```
instance NN Model where 
  type Vector Model = Vec

  compute m = ....  vectorize v ...
```

`compute` uses `vectorize` but this fails to typecheck: GHC says it cannot unifies `Vector a0` with `Vec` and variable `a0` is ambiguous.

I somehow understand why typechecking would fail in the general case of calling `vectorize` with only typeclass constraint: As type family `Vector` is open, there is no way, given a particular `Vector a` image to infer which `a` it is. Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36175839/type-ambiguity-in-haskell-type-families) I also can understand why it fail to typechecks in the particular case of a call from within a method defined in the same instance: At call site of `vectorize` there is no relationship between the `a` of `Vector a -> WordVector` and the `a` of `compute`.

What I don't understand is why the declaration of `vectorize` is not rejected by the compiler.  Following [this page](https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC/Type_families) and the referenced papers, I found the following statement in [this paper](http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~chak/papers/CKP05.html):

> Each method must mention the class variable somewhere that is not
>   under an associated synonym. For example, this declaration defines an
>   unconditionally-ambiguous method op, and is rejected:
>
> ```
>   class C a where
>      type S a
>      op :: S a → Int
> ```

Edit: I am using GHC 7.8.3

Comment: In GHC 8.0 it is rejected. I just tried `class D a where type G a ; bar :: G a -> Int` and an ambiguity error is raised.

Comment: The same example compiles in GHC 8.0 with the `AllowAmbiguousTypes` extension. (Was that enabled, maybe by some other extension, in 7.8.3 ?)